# Opening a .rrd file format in QGIS 2.6?

Tags: qgis, format, files

Anyone knows how can i open a .rrd file (should be a raster)in QGIS 2.6? Comes with more 3 files. 
Should be any difference using it in OS or Windows?

[image]

Comment: RRD stands for "redused resolution dataset" and as far as I know the file contains pyramid layers / overview layers of the main dataset. Most often they are used together with ERDAS .img format but ERDAS does create them for other formats as well. Don't you have the main image files like "Sal_28.tif" available?

Comment: @MappaGnosis I think your comment is worth to be a regular answer.

Answer (score 1):

*Comment converted to answer and slightly extended following @AndreJ's suggestion:*

The [RRD](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009t00000025000000) (Reduced Resolution Dataset) is a proprietary pyramids file. ArcGIS will make them for any raster not just IMG. Don't try to open it as it is not compatible with GDAL (the primary underlying raster tech in QGIS) and does not contain the original data anyway. The only file you should attempt to open is the TIF file itself. The [AUX](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Auxiliary_files/009t00000027000000/) contains statistics and some geopositional information. It is where Arc stores the results when you [calculate statistics](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000m3000000) on a raster.  The AUX is also proprietary.

Most GIS packages will generate a pyramids file either automatically and/or on command.  If the raster contains the georeferencing in its own header, then the AUX can also be safely ignored because, again, the statistics information can be regenerated automatically or on command by most GIS packages (since QGIS is sort of a 'meta-GIS' containing more than three other raster technologies, it is very well provided for in that department).

Comment: Gdal does support .rrd, see `gdaladdo` flag `--config USE_RRD=YES|NO`. Though maybe it uses the same extension for a different internal structure? The nub of the answer is dead on though, open the tiff; the other files are side-car metadata.